# Why does thallium form TlF and TlF3 but aluminium only forms AlF3?

Tags: physical-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, halides

Does this have something to do with the *inert pair effect*?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Answer (score 7):

Ahh, Thallium is a very nice element. *Because it's weird*.

> The +3 oxidation states are favorable except for the heavier elements, such as Tl, which prefer the +1 oxidation state due to its stability; this is known as the inert pair effect. [Chemwiki.UCDavis](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Inorganic_Chemistry/Descriptive_Chemistry/p-Block_Elements/Group_13%3A_The_Boron_Family)
>
> As an example in group 13 the +1 oxidation state of Tl is the most stable and Tl(III) compounds are comparatively rare. [**Inert pair effect**, Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inert_pair_effect)

### So, why?

Inert pair effect was introduced to describe why the facts above are correct. However, the original explanation, provided by Sidgwick, relied on the fact that the $s$ subshell has an "inert" pair of electrons. This can't be correct, and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inert_pair_effect#Description) uses the trend in ionization potentials of "$s$" electrons to prove it wrong:
$$\ce{In < Al < Tl < Ga}$$

A better explanation lies within the lower bond enthalpies of $\ce{MX}$ where M is one of the p-block heavy elements.

To reach a high oxidation number, elements will need to have a strong bond. They wanna bond in order to lose energy (i.e. become more stable) after all! If the bond is weak, this energy isn't provided. Thus, a heavy element is better off with being less oxidised.

See [this](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00045a027) and [this](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/j150561a027). (Sorry, they might be behind a paywall)

Comment: -1, inert pair effect is definitely a real thing; it's due to the lanthanide contraction for the 6p elements + relativistic 6s contraction (the "inert pair"). Also, the thallium halides aren't molecular so invoking bond enthalpies doesn't give the full picture either.

Comment: Hmm...@J.LS I never said it's not real. Just that the description isn't very authentic. (Or rather, the first description) How do you explain the trend in ionization potentials?

Comment: @J.LS Figures out, the pattern in ionization potentials **is** due to the relativistic effects you mention.

Comment: No, the pattern in ionization potentials is due to the transition metal and lanthanide contractions and the associated decrease in shielding for Ga/Tl respectively; relativistic effects are only important for Tl and probably are of secondary importance.